# get java.lang.IllegalStateException error on google play crash summary

Tags: android, stack-trace

google play console crash details give me this error

```
java.lang.Illeg`enter code here`alStateException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1379)
  at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps (BackStackRecord.java:465)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2076)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManagerImpl.java:310)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManagerImpl.java:253)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.handleOnBackPressed (FragmentManagerImpl.java:233)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.handleOnBackPressed (FragmentManagerImpl.java:108)
  at androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed (OnBackPressedDispatcher.java:189)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onBackPressed (ComponentActivity.java:286)
  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp (Activity.java:3252)
  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:2772)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:3559)
  at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent (ComponentActivity.java:122)
  at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
  at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (ComponentActivity.java:140)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatActivity.java:569)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3054)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:427)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5660)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:5528)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4980)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:5033)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4999)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5154)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5211)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4980)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:5033)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4999)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4980)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:5033)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4999)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5187)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5351)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run (InputMethodManager.java:2783)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback (InputMethodManager.java:2291)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent (InputMethodManager.java:2282)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished (InputMethodManager.java:2758)
  at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished (InputEventSender.java:141)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:386)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7625)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

i use one activity with framelayout and load multi fragment on this framelayout based on navigation bar
can't see the problem on my test devices just get this stack trace can any one help
i use this code to switch between fragments

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.animation_fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                assert selectedFragment != null;
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
```

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics will have more details. Seems like The error occurs on the back press button. Is there some animation on the fragment? How are you navigating between fragment

Comment: FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.animation_fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                assert selectedFragment != null;
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

Answer (score 0):

Using custom animation can cause an error. That's why I asked you in the comments section about animation. because a month ago I also fixed the same error. Navigating between fragments too quickly will reproduce this error. remove the following line.

```
 setCustomAnimations(R.anim.animation_fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

secondly, I don't recommend using assert, use if(frag!=null) for the null check.